# Locate code author (annotate/blame) in place

Tags: intellij-idea

Besides having this "annotate" option on the "Differences Viewer" located on the left side of a class, there is a new feature in IntelliJ for locating code author and commit message in place.
For example, if you have your cursor on some code in Java class, a grey text will be displayed beside the java line of code, containing the Author and his commit message for this line. See image below.
[screenshot from IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7i6S.png)
My IntelliJ is up-to-date 2019.2, but I never had this feature. Does someone know how to enable it or get it to work on my workplace?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin.

Comment: Is there something like this for SVN?